# SharePoint 2013 - Show alpha order of search results, on page load

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within the SharePoint search results web part, is there something I can do to list ranked results in alpha order by file name, instead of by their ranked position?

My query builder system is showing the results I want. But when I go outside of query builder, and then depend on the settings of the SharePoint search results web part, listing ranked results is one of the options, which is fine....I just need the results in alpha order when the page loads.

**Or** if there way to avoid the whole ranked listings, and simply show me all my results on an initial page load, before the user types anything into the search box, that would be awesome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try sorting as in below image? You can sort just by filename if that's what you want.
Also, if your query builder returns results by default (without entering search criteria), the search results should show up by default on page load.

[image]